# Proving $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse

Given a function $f~:~X\to Y$ and a set $A\subseteq X$, we wish to prove the following:

$$A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$$

My attempt:

Let $x\in A$.  This implies $\exists y\in Y$ such that $f(x)=y$

Then $f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y)=x$.  Is this right?

Comment: It is difficult to read what you intend due to poor formatting.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to type with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ on the site.  Are you wishing to prove that given a function $f~:~X\to Y$ and $A\subseteq X$ that $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$?

Comment: You should be aware that $f^{-1}$ is not necessarily a function, in particular for functions $f$ which are not injections, so it does not make sense to talk about $f^{-1}(y)=x$.  Take for example the constant function $f(x)=1$.  You have $f(0)=1$ as well as $f(2)=1$, but $f^{-1}(1)$ is not a specific number.

Comment: You need to use your definitions for what $f(A)$ means for $A$ a subset of the domain of $f$ and what $f^{-1}(B)$ means for $B$ a subset of the codomain.

Comment: I will say it again, use your definition for what $f^{-1}(B)$ means.  So, $x\in A$ and $f(x)=y\in f(A)$.  Since $f^{-1}(B)$ represents the set of all...(*insert definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ here*)... it follows that $x\in f^{-1}(f(A))$ by definition.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much for your answer.It helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in A$, then $f(a) \in f(A)$.  Thus $ a \in f^{-1}(f(A))$.